# left side bar not open in apple devices foundation6

Tags: ios, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using foundation6 to build left side bar ([example here](http://foundation.zurb.com/templates-previews-sites-f6/portfolio.html))

the problem is that in the in all apple devices the menu not opening. when i click the burger icon the screen became white and nothing happen.

my code is like this:

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrapper" >
<div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner"  data-off-canvas-wrapper>
    <div class="off-canvas position-left reveal-for-large" id="sideBar" data-off-canvas data-position="left">
        <div class="sideBarDrakBG">
            <div class="row column">
                <a href="/" class="siteLogo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row column">

            </div>
            <div class="row column">
                <div class="sidebarBtns">

                    <a href="#" class="generalCTA joinGreen">bla bla</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row column">
            <div class="sideBarwinners">
                <div class="title"><img src="/skin/images/latest_winners.png"></div>
                <!--  some content</!-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content >
        <div class="title-bar hide-for-large">
            <div class="title-bar-left">
                <div class="menu-iconBG">
                    <button class="menu-icon js-off-canvas-exit" type="button" data-open="sideBar" aria-controls="sideBar"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="title-bar-middle">
                <div class="title-bar-title"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="title-bar-right">
                <a href="#" class="title-bar-login">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainContainer"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

can someone help please?
Thanks
Eli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my problem.
I had to add this to my CSS file:

```
.off-canvas-wrapper {
overflow: hidden;}
```

Now its working.